# How can I add an ImageView to an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

How do I add ImageViews to an ArrayAdapter to show them in my ListView? I tried making the adapter an `ArrayAdapter<ImageView>`, but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
package com.example.picscroller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<ImageView> myarrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(myarrayAdapter);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    final Button removeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeButton);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    ImageView droid = new ImageView(this);
    droid.setImageResource(R.drawable.droid);
    myarrayAdapter.add(droid);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

}
```

...and here's what happened:
[image]
I understand why it happened but how can I make it work (how do I add an ImageView to a ListView/ArrayAdapter?)
Thanks.

**EDIT** Okay, I get that AndroidUniversalImageLoader might be useful but how do I use it @**RSenApps**

Comment: Your getView should return a view having ImageView or just return imageView, ArrayAdapter<Model>, you do not put UI here but data, lets say an array of icons u would use ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>.

Comment: Do you specifically want to have a `ListView` with `ImageViews`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this yourself, I highly recommend using https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader, it will make your life a lot easier and will probably look nicer too!

Comment: Any tutorials on how to use it?

Comment: And how should I use it to put an image into the list?

Comment: Just look at the documentation it should be pretty self explanatory. Also instead of doing your own list you would use their components this also means you can lazy load the images

Comment: start here: http://www.intexsoft.com/blog/item/68-universal-image-loader-part-1.html

Comment: You are most likely going to want to use GridView instead of ListView as you don't need images to fill the whole row